# get row index of signal sender emitted from cell widget in QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have a `QTableWidget` with 3 columns. 
The first two columns store a `QDateTimeEdit` item.
The third stores a `QSpinBox` which should list the duration between the two `QDateTimeEdit` values in this row.

How can I connect a signal of the `QDateTimeEdit` to automatically update the duration in the `QSpinBox` in case one date-time is changed?

```
...
for (int i_row = 0; i_row < 100; ++i_row){
    QTableWidget *t = ui->tableWidget;
    QDateTimeEdit *start = new QDateTimeEdit();
    QDateTimeEdit *end   = new QDateTimeEdit();
    t->setCellWidget(i_row,0,start);
    t->setCellWidget(i_row,1,end);

    QSpinBox *sp = new QSpinBox();
    sp->setReadOnly(true);
    t->setCellWidget(i_row,2,sp);

    connect(start, SIGNAL(dateTimeChanged(const QDateTime &)), this, SLOT(adjustDuration()));
    connect(end,   SIGNAL(dateTimeChanged(const QDateTime &)), this, SLOT(adjustDuration()));
}
```

with the slot:

```
void mainWindow::adjustDuration()
{
    QDateTimeEdit *s = qobject_cast<QDateTimeEdit *>(sender());
    // How do I get row number of the sender within QTableWidget in order to be able to access proper 2nd QDateTimeEdit and QSpinBox? 
    // Simplified speaking: I would like to get the value i_row from the code before
}
```

I suppose it is somehow possible by using the `->parent()` function?

Comment: But aren't your rows and columns static? I.e. your widgets always have predefined row/column values. Why do you need to calculate them?

Comment: no, the value of QDateTimeEdit can be changed by the user within the GUI. Only the spin box is `readOnly`

Comment: The value can be changed but positions of `QDateTimeEdit` remain the same in the `QTableWidget` if am not mistaken. Hence @vahancho suggest could be a straighforward way to solve your problem.

Comment: I have updated the example. In my case, there are many rows of these three items and I need to get which item from which row is sending the signal in order to be able to select the proper counterpart (2nd `QDateTimeEdit` in the same row) to calculate and update the proper `QSpinBox`

Comment: Why not just connect the `dateTimeChanged` signal to a `lambda` that captures `start`, `end` and `sp`?  Then you can do as you please.

Comment: @G.M. sounds like an excellent idea. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using `Qt5` then you could make use of a `lambda`.  So something like (untested)...

```
for (int i_row = 0; i_row < 100; ++i_row){
    QTableWidget *t = ui->tableWidget;
    QDateTimeEdit *start = new QDateTimeEdit();
    QDateTimeEdit *end   = new QDateTimeEdit();
    t->setCellWidget(i_row, 0, start);
    t->setCellWidget(i_row, 1, end);

    QSpinBox *sp = new QSpinBox();
    sp->setReadOnly(true);
    t->setCellWidget(i_row, 2, sp);

    auto eval = [start, end, sp]()
                {

                    /*
                     * Here you have 'start', 'end' and 'sp'.  Use them
                     * in whatever way you see fit.
                     */
                };

    connect(start, &QDateTimeEdit::dateTimeChanged, eval);
    connect(end,   &QDateTimeEdit::dateTimeChanged, eval);
}
```